# How do I set the click method on a TTButton?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, three20

I'm using TTCatalog and creating a TTButton using the following:

```
TTButton *button = [TTButton buttonWithStyle:@"toolbarButton:" title:@"click button"];
```

I tried adding a target and an action to that, but that doesn't work. How do I use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the "[".

```
TTButton *button = [TTButton buttonWithStyle:@"toolbarButton:" title:@"click button"];
[button setUserInteractionEnabled:YES]; 
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then just set button properties, use target/action to set an event handler.  (The TTButton is just a UIEvent subclass.)

Good luck!